# Entity Framework: can't compile after changing FKs to "delete cascade"

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a lookup table with 2 columns, each column is a FK. Let's say those columns are CustomerID and ProductID. Everything was ok until I changed those FKs to have the "delete rule" and "update rule" on both to Cascade. No I cannot build the project. Any solutions?

Comment: Where did you change the rule and what error do you receive?

Comment: I made changes in db. I can't get the exact error (not in my office right now) but it complains something about "relationship" between the two main tables that the lookup tbl "links" together.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed the rule in SQL Server, you have to update your model from database.

If you changed the rule in the .edmx file manually, first make sure that you still have well-formed xml and then re-generate the DDL and redeploy the database.

Comment: Making changes in the database will not break the build.

Comment: I updated the model after I made those changes in db. That pretty much broke the project and created the problem.